# Is it possible to bind two entities as ManyToMany without extra class?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two entities, say,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
    // ...
}
```

In the database, I have tables `customers`, `products` and `customers_products`, which, respectively, store data about customers, products and their relations.

That hold many-to-many relationship (a customer can add multiple products, and each product can be added by multiple customers). So I add private properties to each of entities and annotate them as `@ManyToMany`.

Should I, after that, explicitly add a class `ProductCustomer` that mimics DB table `products_customers`, or would a proper `@ManyToMany` config be enough? In case the latter, what direction should I look to find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

A `ManyToMany` relationship in Java is where the source object has an attribute that stores a collection of target objects and (if) those target objects had the `inverse` relationship back to the source object it would also be a `ManyToMany` relationship. All relationships in Java and `JPA` are unidirectional, in that if a source object references a target object there is no guarantee that the target object also has a relationship to the source object. This is different than a relational database, in which relationships are defined through `foreign keys` and querying such that the `inverse` query always exists.

Typically, a `join table` is created to connect two primary tables in order to make the association.

Normally the `join table`  has only two fields `(entity_A_id and entity_B_id)` that refer to two `primary keys` of the main tables groups and users. This couple of fields is also called as a `composite primary key`.

> Until this, going with two classes is absolutely fine, no need of
>   creating and managing the 3rd joint class.

Now, let suppose you wish to `modify the Joint Table`, meaning entering more fields into it etc. The you need to create the 3rd class, with table name same as joint table name.

for [ref](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example).

Comment: `join table` with two fields composing a unique pair approach is okay for my situation, thanks.